# Unable to run Jest tests. Getting Error unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babel-jest

I am unable run tests using jest. Writing tests for react application. Getting following error :-

```
node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css:5
     *//*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css
 */html{font-family:sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjus
t:100%}body{margin:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgrou
p,main,menu,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,progress,video{displa
y:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height
:0}[hidden],template{display:none}a{background-color:transparent}a:active,a:hove
r{outline:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:700}dfn{fo
nt-style:italic}h1{margin:.67em 0;font-size:2em}mark{color:#000;background:#ff0}
small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{position:relative;font-size:75%;line-height:0;vertic
al-align:baseline}sup{top:-.5em}sub{bottom:-.25em}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){ov
erflow:hidden}figure{margin:1em 40px}hr{height:0;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
-moz-box-sizing
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

  at transformAndBuildScript (node_modules\jest-cli\node_modules\jest-runtim
e\build\transform.js:320:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Saroj,

You're getting the error: "Unexpected token {" because you have not closed the last curly brace in the sample you've provided. Simply add a curly brace at the end of your last css style on the element "hr" and you will no longer see this error.

```
    hr {height:0;
        -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
        -moz-box-sizing
        }
```